# Pass Module attribute as an argument to Macros

Tags: elixir

It's [common to have constants as Module Attributes](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html#as-constants) in Elixir. I've tried to pass module attributes as arguments to different macros from different libraries (that usually define a new module):

```ex
defmodule X do
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]
  @another_constant "some-constant-value"

  defenum DataType, :type, @data_types
end
```

<sup>*Here's another example of [passing module attributes as an argument to a Macro](https://github.com/meh/amnesia/issues/66)*</sup>

---

**But almost always get an error along the same lines:**

```ex
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:@, [line: 26], [{:types, [line: 26], nil}]}
```

So I usually end up repeating the values:

```ex
defmodule X do
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]
  @another_constant "some-constant-value"

  defenum DataType, :type, [:x, :y, :z]
end
```

I know repeating them most of the time isn't usually a big deal, but I would really like to know how would I be able to pass the value of a module attribute to a macro.

This is especially apparent in macros that define new modules (like [`Amnesia`](https://github.com/meh/amnesia/) and [`EctoEnum`](https://github.com/gjaldon/ecto_enum)).

---

**So far I've tried a bunch of things, including:**

- Expanding the value using the `Macro` module
- Evaluating the value using `Code` module
- Fetching the value using `Module.get_attribute/2`
- Trying different variations of quote/unquote calls

But nothing has worked. I have a feeling the macro needs to be written in a way that it can read them. If so, how should the macro be written for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to fix the issue with passing arbitrary quoted expressions to external libraries would be *to provide pull requests fixing issues in the libraries*.

Consider the following example

```rb
defmodule Macros do
  defmacro good(param) do
    IO.inspect(param, label: " Passed")
    expanded = Macro.expand(param, __CALLER__)
    IO.inspect(expanded, label: " Expanded")
  end

  defmacro bad(param) do
    IO.inspect(param, label: " Not Expanded")
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  import Macros
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]

  def test do
    good(@data_types)
    bad(@data_types)
  end
end
```

The declaration of `Test` prints:

```rb
 Passed: {:@, [line: 28], [{:data_types, [line: 28], nil}]}
 Expanded: [:x, :y, :z]
 Not Expanded: {:@, [line: 29], [{:data_types, [line: 29], nil}]}
```

If the 3rd-party library does not call [`Macro.expand/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Macro.html#expand/2) on the argument, the quoted expressions won’t be *expanded*. Below is the excerpt from the documentation:

> The following contents are expanded:
>
> • Macros (local or remote)
>   • Aliases are expanded (if possible) and return atoms
>   • Compilation environment macros (`__CALLER__/0`, `__DIR__/0`, `__ENV__/0` and `__MODULE__/0`)
>   • Module attributes reader (`@foo`)

That said, to have the ability to accept module attributes or macro calls like sigils, the 3rd party library macros **must** call `Macro.expand` on arguments. You cannot fix this issue from your client code.

Comment: This seems like what I was looking for. I have no problem sending in PRs to different packages if this can get it to work. :)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `defenum DataType, :type, ~w[x y z]a` won’t work either without `Macro.expand`, that’s why I _always_ use sigils in tests when working with macros.

Comment: That's interesting, didn't know that either. I'll start by updating my own packages and send PRs to others in the next few weeks. Thanks!

Comment: What info does `bad/1` provide that is not provided by `IO.inspect(param, label: " Passed")` inside `good/1`?

Comment: It is redundant, but I found it to be more evident that way.

Comment: What if good and bad functions are invoked outside of def, i.e. at the module level? It seems that it is not expanded to the simple value but to a complex ast.

Answer (score 0):

> But almost always get an error...

I'm able to access a module attribute inside a macro in this example:

```
defmodule My do
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]

  defmacro go() do
    quote do
      def types() do
        unquote(@data_types)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  require My
  My.go()

  def start do
    types()
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> Test.start()
[:x, :y, :z]

iex(2)>
```

**Response to comment:**

Here's an example that passes a module attribute as an argument to a macro function call:

```
defmodule My do

  defmacro go(arg) do
    quote do
      def show do
        Enum.each(unquote(arg), fn x -> IO.inspect x end)
      end
    end
  end

end

defmodule Test do
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]

  require My
  My.go(@data_types)

  def start do
    show()
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> Test.start()
:x
:y
:z
:ok

iex(2)>
```

If instead, you try this:

```
defmodule My do
  defmacro go(arg) do
    Enum.each(arg, fn x -> IO.inspect x end)
  end

end

defmodule Test do
  require My
  @data_types [:x, :y, :z]
  My.go(@data_types)

  def start do
    show()
  end
end
```

then in iex you'll get an error:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:@, [line: 11], [{:data_types, [line: 11], nil}]}
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:141: Enumerable.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1919: Enum.each/2
    expanding macro: My.go/1
    my.exs:11: Test (module)
```

That error occurs because you are trying to enumerate an ast:

```
{:@, [line: 11], [{:data_types, [line: 11], nil}]}
```

which is not a list (or any other enumerable--it's obviously a tuple!).  Remember that arguments to macros are ast's.

The reason this works:

```
  defmacro go(arg) do

    quote do
      def show do
        Enum.each(unquote(arg), fn x -> IO.inspect x end)
      end
    end

  end
```

is because `quote()` creates an ast, and `unquote(arg)` injects some other ast into the middle of the ast.  The macro call `My.go(@data_types)` executes at compile time, and elixir replaces the macro call with the ast returned by `My.go()`, which is a function definition named `show()`.

Comment: I want to pass module attribute values as an argument to the macro, not access it directly (which I know is easy)

Comment: Updated the question title, though I thought the examples in the question already made that pretty clear :)

Comment: @Sheharyar, See additional example at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Your example works because you're defining a method in the same module. It still doesn't solve the problem because `quote(do: unquote(@attr))` is still `@attr` and not it's value. Most library macros generate a new module at compile-time which will not be able to read the value of the module attr passed as arg with this.